# JPA Query with null object

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have the following query:

```
Query query1 = getEntityManager().createQuery(
" select o from Customer o  " +
" where lower(o.person.name) like :name escape '!' " +
" or lower(o.company.name) like :name escape '!'");
```

And my mapping is:

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends AbstractBaseEntity {

@OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Company company;

@OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;
...
}
```

The problem is:
Each `Customer` may be a `Person` **OR** a `Company`, but **not** both at same time.
This means that one of these entities will be always null.

With the query that I wrote, it will only fetch the result when both of the entities are not null, which is a behavior that I didn't expect.

Does anyone know how to create a query that searches for `Person.name` when `Company.name` is null and search for `Company.name` when `Person.name` is null?

I can make 2 separated queries, but I'm trying to do it all just in one query to perform the spring-data-jpa pagination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an explicit `LEFT JOIN` for that:

```
SELECT cu from Customer cu  
LEFT JOIN cu.person p
LEFT JOIN cu.company co
where lower(p.name) like :name escape '!' 
or lower(co.name) like :name escape '!'
```

Comment: Sure! But if the person is null and i'm looking for a comapny name?

Comment: Of course that was only an example to show you the idea :) Answer updated. Please don't tell me now that there is no `SELECT` part in my example :)

Comment: Of course =) Thanks again. Sadly it doesn't works with the OR statement. I execute in separated queries and works normally. This is strange. I've double checked all parameters and syntax...

Comment: Another idea is to use an explict `LEFT JOIN`. If you dont get it, I will post another answer later.

Comment: Nice! It works using left join! Thanks! Just edit your answer with the left join to mark as correct =)